# Creating a new column and inserting data using SQL instructions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called film and from there using LIKE on a column called description I get all the movies that contain the word "kill". Now I want to create a new column called "age_restriction" with the information "18" based on the descriptions in the description column that contains "kill" and keep "null" or "0" to the other values in this column. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Create the new column with an ALTER statement, and then run an UPDATE statement using your LIKE condition. `UPDATE yourtable SET age_restriction = CASE WHEN <your LIKE condition> THEN 18 ELSE 0 END;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a SELECT with a new column:

```
select *, case when description like '%kill%' then '18' else '' end as age_restriction
from film
```

If you want to add a column to your table and update it:

```
alter table film add age_restriction integer;

update film set age_restriction = 18 where description like '%kill%';

select * from film;
```

[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4h5LPYFtWMR5fkiy2uNhEA/1)